# How to store lists of embedded documents with MongoDB under Grails?

Tags: list, mongodb, grails, documents

I'm having problem storing lists of embedded documents/objects in MongoDB using the Grails MongoDB plugin. I used the information given in the [documentation](http://springsource.github.io/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/3.%20Mapping%20Domain%20Classes%20to%20Mongo%20Collections.html) in chapter 3 but only got the embedding of one object working.

For testing purposes I created two domain objects Person and Address in a new Grails project. They look like this:

```
class Person {
    ObjectId id
    String   firstName
    String   lastName
    Address  address
    List     otherAddresses = []
    static embedded = ['address', 'otherAddresses']
}

class Address {
    String street
    String postCode
    String city
}
```

When I execute the following lines in Bootstrap.groovy it stores two Person objects in MongoDB - both have a correct address but in person1 the otherAddresses List is "[  null ]" and in person2 the otherAddresses List is "[ { "street" : "Second Street. 164" , "city" : "New York" , "postCode" : "13579"}]"

```
def address = new Address(street: "Mainstreet. 164", city: "New York", postCode:"12345")
def person1 = new Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe")
person1.address = address
person1.otherAddresses.add(address)
println person1.otherAddresses // Result: "[mongoembeddedlisttest.Address : (unsaved)]"
person1.save()
person1.errors.allErrors.each { println it } // no errors

def person2 = new Person(firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe")
person2.otherAddresses += ['street': 'Second Street. 164', 'city': 'New York', 'postCode':'13579']
println person2.otherAddresses // Result: "[[street:Second Street. 164, city:New York, postCode:13579]]"
person2.save()
```

Resulting Database Entries:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "521089461a150b20390d61c2"} , "address" : { "city" : "New York" , "postCode" : "12345" , "street" : "Mainstreet. 164"} , "firstName" : "John" , "lastName" : "Doe" , "otherAddresses" : [  null ] , "version" : 0}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "521089461a150b20390d61c3"} , "firstName" : "Jane" , "lastName" : "Doe" , "otherAddresses" : [ { "street" : "Second Street. 164" , "city" : "New York" , "postCode" : "13579"}] , "version" : 0}
```

Further Notes:

- I'm using a pure mongodb approach (no a hybrid together with Hibernate)
- I'm working on a Windows 8 machine using Grails 2.2.1 running mongo db 2.4.4
- Person is a domain object in /grails-app/domain and Address is a "normal" groovy class in /src/groovy (I can put it in domain folder but that has no effect)
- Everything is set to be nullable in Config.groovy: grails.gorm.default.constraints = { '*'(nullable: true) }
- BuildConfig.groovy has the plugin entry: compile ":mongodb:1.3.0"

What am I doing wrong? How can I store a list of embedded objects using the Grails mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're adding a map in the second person instead of an Address object. Is there any reason why you're adding the otherAddress different for each person?

I think this should work although I haven't tested it:

```
def address = new Address(street: "Mainstreet. 164", city: "New York", postCode:"12345")
def person1 = new Person(firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe")
person1.address = address
person1.otherAddresses.add(address)
println person1.otherAddresses // Result: "[mongoembeddedlisttest.Address : (unsaved)]"
person1.save()
person1.errors.allErrors.each { println it } // no errors

def person2 = new Person(firstName: "Jane", lastName: "Doe")
person2.otherAddresses += new Address('street': 'Second Street. 164', 'city': 'New York', 'postCode':'13579')
println person2.otherAddresses 
person2.save()
```